# Cassandra nodes extremely unbalanced with Vnodes token strategy

Tags: cassandra

Using the Vnodes strategy with 256 tokens per node, my cluster shows info like below while executing nodetool status. Seems the load of my cluster is extremely unbalanced. I dont know what cause this. Is partition key of tables related ? Any comments would be welcome, Thanks!

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.1.190  9.78 GiB   256          ?       f3e56d8d-caf2-450a-b4f1-e5ac5163a17a  rack1
UN  192.168.1.191  77.53 MiB  256          ?       e464cda9-ca8b-400b-82eb-59256d23c94a  rack1
UN  192.168.1.192  89.31 MiB  256          ?       6feaa65f-2523-4b65-9717-f4f3cbf28ef0  rack1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, most probably there is a skew in the distribution of partition keys, most probably some partitions have much more rows than other.  Check [this document](https://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/dataModel.html) for recommendations, especially the sections "Number of cells per partition" and "Big partitions".  You can use the number of tools to check the hypothesis:

- `nodetool tablehistograms` (may need to be executed for every table separately) on each host will show you the number of cells and partition size in bytes at 50%, 75%, ..., and 100% percentiles.  You may see very big differences between 95% & 100% percentiles.
- `nodetool tablestats` will show the max & average size of the partition per table per host
- [DSBulk](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/07/datastax-bulk-loader-counting) has an option to show the largest partitions based on the number of rows per partition - it needs to be executed for every table in cluster, but only once, not from each host in contrast to the `nodetool`:

```
dsbulk count -k keyspace -t table --log.verbosity 0 --stats.mode partitions
```

Comment: Thanks very much! The command tools above is useful. Currently most keyspaces are with replication-factor of 2, and most talbes with a single column partition key, some other tables with composite parition key of two columns. Tested with command above, the result turn out the parition size and cell count differ from node to node，but not very distinctively. I'll double check my schema and check the document to see if this can be resolved.Thank you very much!

Comment: After checked most tables with tablehistograms tool,I found that most table have a uniform spread of parition key size and cell counts except one. Sorry for the length of content about to paste,would you please check another answer of mine below.

Comment: If the distribution is uniform, then I would say that data is not in sync, as mentioned by Andrew - do you perform repairs regularly?

Comment: Sorry for absence.I just left my desk a while. Plz check the answer below by myself. Most tables are uniform but one. Kairosdb keyspace and data_point table to store time-serial data.The partition size and cell counts differ a lot by percentile.

Comment: It’s not too bad imho, I would do the repair first to see maybe your cluster missed writes

Comment: I dropped some useless keyspaces and alter some keyspaces' replication-factor with 1 and executed "nodetool repair", the nodetool status seems not changed. Node1' load is still much heigher than the others.

Comment: To perform repairs I recommend to use http://cassandra-reaper.io/. Also, lowering RF doesn't automatically remove data - that's the task for nodetool cleanup.  But with RF=1 you have a chance of losing your data, so it's not recommended

Comment: OK, thanks a lot. I' ll try this. But with RF=2 or RF=3, kairosdb query may got absent datas I tried before. Should I change the consistency policy which currently is ONE or my application my not get the right datas? And this may cause query latency I guess.

Comment: And just now my strucutred streaming app halts because "  Not enough replicas available for query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 required but only 0 alive)"

Comment: that's the different issue - this means that replica is not available. Regarding absent data - that's why you need to have repair running regularly - it looks like your machines may miss some data when writing.  I really recommend to go through https://www.datastax.com/resources/ebook/oreilly-cassandra-definitive-guide

Comment: After restart cluster, the loads of nodes finally are uniform. Really don't know what cause the previous status. Thanks a lot Alex! Seems I really need to go through relative documents thoroughly to get a further understanding of architec of Cassandra.

Comment: `--stats.mode` is incorrect. you should use `--stats.modes`!

Comment: Most probably they have changed the command-line options between releases. It was two years since it's answered

Answer (score 2):

Even with a significant imbalance of the primary token range - something about the load is not right - if you are using an RF of 3, all 3 nodes would have a replica of all the data, and any primary range imbalance would not be visible.

To get the imbalance you have posted points to the use of using RF1 - and potentially a poor data model / partition key which is hotspotting the data to a single node.

Comment: Currently most keyspaces are using replication factor of 2.  Most tables are with a single partition key and some of them with composite partition key of two columns. Thanks very much, I 'll check the table schem to find if there is a better schema to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Most tables are uniform but this one

```
kairosdb/data_points histograms  —— NODE1 load 9.73GB
Percentile  SSTables     Write Latency      Read Latency    Partition Size        Cell Count
                              (micros)          (micros)           (bytes)
50%             2.00             17.08            152.32              1597                86
75%             2.00             35.43            182.79              9887               446
95%             2.00             88.15            263.21             73457              3973
98%             2.00            105.78            263.21            315852             20501
99%             2.00            105.78            263.21            545791             29521
Min             2.00              6.87            126.94               104                 0
Max             2.00            105.78            263.21            785939             35425

kairosdb/data_points histograms  —— NODE2 load 36.95MB
Percentile  SSTables     Write Latency      Read Latency    Partition Size        Cell Count
                              (micros)          (micros)           (bytes)
50%             1.00             20.50            454.83              1109                42
75%             2.00             42.51            943.13              9887               446
95%             2.00             73.46          14530.76             73457              3973
98%             2.00            219.34          14530.76            263210             17084
99%             2.00            219.34          14530.76            545791             29521
Min             1.00              8.24             88.15               104                 0
Max             2.00            219.34          14530.76            785939             35425

kairosdb/data_points histograms  —— NODE3 load 61.56MB
Percentile  SSTables     Write Latency      Read Latency    Partition Size        Cell Count
                              (micros)          (micros)           (bytes)
50%             1.00             14.24            943.13              1331                50
75%             1.00             29.52           1131.75              9887               446
95%             1.00             61.21           1131.75             73457              3973
98%             1.00            152.32           1131.75            315852             17084
99%             1.00            654.95           1131.75            545791             29521
Min             1.00              4.77            785.94                73                 0
Max             1.00            654.95           1131.75            785939             35425
```